# Magento 2: How to override the crontab.xml of CustomModule1 from CustomModule2?

Tags: overrides, crontab, magento2.2.2

**How can I override the crontab.xml of CustomModule1 from CustomModule2?**

I know that if it was a Magento module from vendor I could just use the same path on app/code to override it, but I need a way to change the schedule on the crontab.xml of an extension that wasn't installed with composer, without changing the original.

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve so we can help to sort out you problem.

Comment: If you want to change the frequency of when the cron runs, which is what I think you're trying to ask, you can "override" it in the database table core_config _data with a path like this: crontab/default/jobs/my_cron_job/schedule/cron_expr' and set the value to whatever cron expression you want (e.g. */5 * * * *)

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is described in the question: "I need a way to change the schedule on the crontab.xml of an extension that wasn't installed with composer, without changing the original". I need to know how to do that (if it's possible) from a custom module (something that can be commited using Git & that I can replicate to other projects).

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved by by overriding the `crontab.xml` file of CustomModule1 in your CustomModule2.

For testing purpose, I have overridden a few crons from `Magento_Indexer` module in my custom module as given below.

Added following code to `etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Amitshree_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Indexer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

And added below code to `etc/crontab.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="index">
        <job name="indexer_reindex_all_invalid" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\ReindexAllInvalid" method="execute">
            <schedule>5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="indexer_update_all_views" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\UpdateMview" method="execute">
            <schedule>9 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="indexer_clean_all_changelogs" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\ClearChangelog" method="execute">
            <schedule>4 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Question**: How to verify it works properly?

**Answer**: Follow below steps to verify it.

- After making above changes flush your cache.
- run command `php bin/magento cron:run` from root of your project
- Connect to your database via sql command `use magento2;`
- ### run below sql queries

1. `select job_code, scheduled_at from cron_schedule where job_code = 'indexer_reindex_all_invalid';`

Output:

```
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| job_code                    | scheduled_at        |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
| indexer_reindex_all_invalid | 2020-02-26 11:05:00 |
+-----------------------------+---------------------+
```

2. `select job_code, scheduled_at from cron_schedule where job_code = 'indexer_update_all_views';`

Output:

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| job_code                 | scheduled_at        |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
| indexer_update_all_views | 2020-02-26 11:09:00 |
+--------------------------+---------------------+
```

3. `select job_code, scheduled_at from cron_schedule where job_code = 'indexer_clean_all_changelogs';`

Output:

```
+------------------------------+---------------------+
| job_code                     | scheduled_at        |
+------------------------------+---------------------+
| indexer_clean_all_changelogs | 2020-02-26 11:04:00 |
+------------------------------+---------------------+
```